# how to identify a view object without assigning its tag property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I place  textview in the prototype cells by storyboard and assign the textview's tag.

In the implantation method of 
`-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,

I wanna assign the textview another identifier so that I can obtain the textview by this identifier. The reason why I don't use the TAG property to do this is because that all the cells in my table view has the same prototype for reusing.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    ETPost *post = postList[indexPath.row];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:TEXT_TAG];//TEXT_TAG 1000
    textView.text =post.content;
    return cell;
}
```

as you can see above, I use the viewWithTag, all the cells in my tableview have the same tag, so I have to another solution instead of assigning the indexPath to the TAG.

Comment: Can you try to describe the desired end result? What is it exactly you want to do when obtaining the textview by its identifier? - You should know that the UITableViewCell's gets reused once they drop off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: what I wanna do is that after assign an identifier of the textview, I could identify the textview other place such as the delegate method of -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView so I could know which piece of data is being edited. I could not use the tag because I already assign the tag. All the reusable cells have the same tag. So, I don't know which specific textview is being edited.

Comment: one option would be to make the cell the delegate of the text view. the cell can know which item it is associated with. it can then send a message to the responder chain including the item being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the answer is probably simpler than you think. But just subclass UITableViewCell and make sure that your table view is using your new subclass (you set this up in the prototype cell Custom Class in IB and StoryBoards). The only thing the subclass adds is a property that allows you to identify it.

```
@property short specialIdentifier;
```

Here's a more general link on UITableViewCells which I generally refer to when I need something done: [cusomizing uitableviewcells](http://blog.giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/)

Answer (score 0):

in `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you could assign the indexPath's row number to your textView's tag like:

```
cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

so this tag would correspond with your cell's indexPath distinct assuming you place all cells in ONE section.

Comment: It does not work in my context.  I already assign the tag of the textview in storyboard.

Comment: what I wanna do is that after assign an identifier of the textview, I could identify the textview other place such as the delegate method of -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView so I could know which piece of data is being edited. I could not use the tag because I already assign the tag. All the reusable cells have the same tag. So, I don't know which specific textview is being edited

Comment: I don't understand what aim you're trying to achieve. be more concrete which "other place" you mean.

Comment: in my answer's code the tag of your textField you assigned would be overwritten for each new cell created (displayed) so each textField's tag would be the distinct index of your datasource's element being edited.